# Can you use semicolons in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

When learning Ruby, I noticed that in all the examples there are no semicolons. I am aware that this is perfectly fine as long as each statement is on its own line. But what I am wondering is, *can* you use semicolons in Ruby?

Comment: And to the Ruby folks out there: Should one use semicolons?  Is there benefit in doing so?  I know that when I write Ruby code, I reflexively add them.

Comment: @Andy Don't use semicolons, unless you want to put multiple statements on one line, which [you should avoid doing anyway](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#semicolon).

Comment: @Yaser: I kind of need semicolons. Because when there is a function on a line without a semicolon, vim autoindents for me, which I do not want happening.

Comment: You may want to ask a question about that, because there's a fair few people who use vim with ruby.

Comment: The link in the comment by @YaserSulaiman gives the argument that semicolons make code less legible and are ugly. It's a valid opinion, but it's an opinion.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Yes.

> Ruby doesn't require us to use any character to separate commands, unless we want to chain multiple statements together on a single line. In this case, a semicolon (;) is used as the separator.

Source: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/learn-ruby-on-rails/2

Comment: but should I use semicolon?

Comment: @rocketspacer That's an entirely different question

Answer (score 41):

As a side note, it's useful to use semi-colons in your (j)irb session to avoid printing out a ridiculously long expression value, e.g.

```
irb[0]> x = (1..1000000000).to_a
[printout out the whole array]
```

vs

```
irb[0]> x = (1..100000000).to_a; nil
```

Nice especially for your MyBigORMObject.find_all calls.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, semicolons can be used as statement separators in Ruby.

Though my typical style (and *most* code I see) puts a line of code on each line, so the use of `;` is pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Semicolon: yes.

```
irb(main):018:0> x = 1; c = 0
=> 0
irb(main):019:0> x
=> 1
irb(main):020:0> c
=> 0
```

You can even run multiple commands separated by semicolons in a one-liner loop

```
irb(main):021:0> (c += x; x += 1) while x < 10
=> nil
irb(main):022:0> x
=> 10
irb(main):023:0> c
=> 45
```

Answer (score 4):

The only situation I've come across that semicolons are useful is when declaring alias methods for attr_reader.

Consider the following code:

```
attr_reader :property1_enabled
attr_reader :property2_enabled
attr_reader :property3_enabled

alias_method :property1_enabled?, :property1_enabled
alias_method :property2_enabled?, :property2_enabled
alias_method :property3_enabled?, :property3_enabled
```

By using semicolons we can reduce this down 3 lines:

```
attr_reader :property1_enabled; alias_method :property1_enabled?, :property1_enabled
attr_reader :property2_enabled; alias_method :property2_enabled?, :property2_enabled
attr_reader :property3_enabled; alias_method :property3_enabled?, :property3_enabled
```

To me this doesn't really take away from readability.

Answer (score 2):

It can be interesting to use semicolons to preserve the block syntax as in this example:

```
a = [2, 3 , 1, 2, 3].reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h, num| h[num] += 1; h }
```

You maintain one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting lines with semicolons is something very important sometimes.

Say you want to calculate something trivial like depositing your money and want to calculate inflation. And let's say you don't want to do it in irb (because it's terribly buggy), you can use your shell, and a semicolon is needed:

```
$ ruby -e "x = 7_200 ; 10.times { x += (x * 6.6 / 100.0) } ; puts x"
13642.832381464528
```

Same thing applies if you want to quickly parse JSON or so just from the command shell or want to do something really quick.

There's a clear advantage of having blocks over languages that uses indentation instead of blocks. And semicolons are helpful to join multiple lines.

In most cases using a semicolon is a bad idea in Ruby. But in some cases it's mandatory. For example, consider this valid ruby code:

```
def x(*)
  5
end

p x 1, '', [1,2,3], {1 => '1'}    # => 5
```

Above code works completely fine.

In ruby, you can use `arg` instead of `(arg)`. In case of `*` though, you need a semicolon if you plan to omit the parentheses.

So this won't work:

```
def x *
  5
end

p x 1, '', [1,2,3], {5 => '5'}
```

But this will:

```
def x *;
  5
end

p x 1, '', [1,2,3], {5 => '5'}
```

You can also use `def x*;`. But the parser can't parse your code if you miss the semicolon (tried ruby 1.9 to 3.1).

So there are some cases like these where semicolons are needed much like JavaScript. And such code aren't probably clean code.