# puts doesn't print stuff to console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, console, logging

i'm using [POW](http://pow.cx/) for local rails development. i don't know why, but i can't **print** or **puts** information to my development.log. i want to puts the content of variables to console / log from my controller. any advice?

i read my logs with `tail -f logs/development.log`

thanks!

Comment: As a note, puts has NEVER written stuff to the log - its used for stdout.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of `puts`, try `logger.info()`. [Logging in Rails](http://mikenaberezny.com/2007/02/24/rails-logging-tips/) is very flexible, but it does mean that you might not be able to use the simplest tools sometimes.

Comment: And remember to create a logger object from Logger.

Comment: People keep recommending to use the logger for this, but if you use `puts` then you get to see your data immediately in the console, being printed as the code runs, meanwhile by using the logger you have to look inside a text file that doesn't auto-update depending on the text editor you use, resulting in a much clunkier user experience.

Comment: @bpromas, I strongly recommend `tail -F` or `less +F` for following log files.

Comment: This should be `Rails.logger.info`, not `logger.info`. The plain `logger` variable is only available in a few specific types of Rails files, such as controllers.

Answer (score 11):

If you're doing debugging and only want to see some messages in the logs you can do the following:

```
Rails.logger.debug("debug::" + person.name)
```

and

```
$ pow logs | grep debug::
```

now you'll only see logging messages that start with debug::

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the rails tagging logger, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TaggedLogging.html.

```
logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
logger.tagged('BCX') { logger.info 'Stuff' }                            # Logs "[BCX] Stuff"

$ pow logs | grep BCX
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still can't get it to work, remember that Ruby doesn't use semicolons.  They are only used to [chain commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953856/539149).  I was adding them at the end due to muscle memory (coming from PHP), so the ruby console thought I was still entering commands:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "hi";
irb(main):002:0* puts "hi"
hi
hi
=> nil
```

Hope this helps someone.