# How can I print data using the puts statement to development.log file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

When I write `Print statements` those are not getting printed in the `log/development.log file` when I'm working in development mode. How can I make `puts` statement work in `development.log` file in rails?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [puts doesn't print stuff to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673584/puts-doesnt-print-stuff-to-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (from inside of an controller):

```
def some_method
  pi = 3.1514
  logger.debug "Debug message"
  logger.info "Info message"
  logger.info "PI equals #{pi}"
end
```

There are 5 types of messages: DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

I recommend reading this chapter from Rails Guides: [**2.3 Sending Messages**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger)

Answer (score 1):

To write to your log file you should use

```
logger.debug "Anything"
```

Please note that the file (development, production, test) depends on the environment you are actually using