# Assign nested attributes records to current user when using Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, assign, cocoon-gem

In my application I have models `Post` & `Slides` & I have:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :slides, inverse_of: :post
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :slides, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Everything works fine, only thing I need *(because of how my application will work)*, is when a `slide` is created, I need to **assign** it to `current_user` or user that is creating the record.

I already have `user_id` in my `slides` table and:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :slide
end

class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

*My `PostsController` looks like this:*

```
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build

    // This is for adding a slide without user needing to click on link_to_add_association when they enter new page/action
    @post.slides.build
  end


  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

First option: when saving the slide, fill in the user-id, but this will get pretty messy quickly. You either do it in the model in a `before_save`, but how do you know the current-user-id? Or do it in the controller and change the user-id *if not set* before saving/after saving.

There is, however, an easier option :) Using the `:wrap_object` option of the `link_to_add_association` ([see doc](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#wrap_object)) you can prefill the `user_id` in the form! So something like:

```
= link_to_add_association ('add slide', @form_obj, :slides,
      wrap_object: Proc.new {|slide| slide.user_id = current_user.id; slide })
```

To be completely correct, you would also have to change your `new` method as follows

```
@post.slides.build(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Then of course, we have to add the `user_id` to the form, as a hidden field, so it is sent back to the controller, and do not forget to fix your strong parameters clause to allow setting the `user_id` as well :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `slide` located after the ";"?  ... does it store two variables in the `|slide|`?

Comment: From the documentation: `Note that the :wrap_object expects an object that is callable, so any Proc will do. So you could as well use it to do some fancy extra initialisation (if needed). But note you will have to return the (nested) object you want used.`. So we receive the initialised nested object, the `slide`, do something with it (set the `user_id`), and then return it so it is then used to render the partial (with the set `user_id`).

Comment: @nathanvda thanks for you answer. I added new things to `link_to_add_association` and also in my controller, but I got this error: `undefined method "object" for nil:NilClass`. What have I dont wrong?

Comment: Its more the mechanics...I can see the the assignment in the first part, but the ; is throwing me since normally I only see that in other languages like C

Comment: Can you show me your `link_to_add_association` line, otherwise it is bit hard to just guess, well, I can guess: are you using the correct form object? (generally it is `f`, here I used `@form_obj` as an example --> you did not just copy that verbatim?)

Comment: Yeah I found out about and changed it to `f` and I didnt got the error, but user_id is not saving into record. Here is my link: `= link_to_add_association "add slide", f, :slides, wrap_object: Proc.new {|slide| slide.user_id = current_user.id; slide }` & My controller `new` action: `@post.slides.build(user_id: current_user)`

Comment: @Mirv the `;` does exactly the same as in c,  so it allows me to write it one line :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953846/can-you-use-semicolons-in-ruby

Comment: You will prob have to fix your strong parameters to allow setting the `user_id` (there should be an error in the log that it is rejected).

Comment: Here is my strong parameters in my `PostsController`: `slides_attributes: [:id, :title, :description, :user_id, :post_id, :_destroy]` thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Ow: do you have a hidden field in the form for your `user_id`??? Otherwise it is not sent at all (so obvious I forgot to mention that).

Answer (score 1):

When I'm looking at this I see three ways to go about it, but since you're on cocoon already, I would drop the connection between user & slides - as it kind of violates good database practices (until you hit a point where you page is so popular you have to optimize of course, but that would be done differently).

You are using cocoon, but you're not utilizing the nesting of the relationship fully yet ...

The best practice would be to have cocoon's nesting create both & instead of trying to assign to `current_user` you call something like:

```
@slides = current_user.posts.find_first(param[:id]).slides
```

The `@slides` saves all the results, the `.Post.find(param[:id])` finds a specific post for `current_user`.

***Note***:  this is not the most optimized way & I haven't tested this, but it shows you the format of one way you can think about the relationships.  You will need to hit `rails console` and run some tests like ...

```
 (rails console)> @user = User.first
```

Next we test that there are posts available, as it's frustrating to test blanks & not get the results ...

```
(rails console)> @posts = @user.posts
```

Then we use the `find` method & I'm going to use `Post.first` just to get a working id, you can easily put "1" or any number you know is valid ...

```
(rails console)> @post = @posts.find(Post.first)
```

Finally, we go with either all slides to make sure its a valid dataset

```
(rails console)> @post.slides
```

If you want a specific slide later & have a `has_many` relationship just tag that `find` method on the `.slides` after.

Also one last thing - when you state earlier in there you need the current_user to be related, you can use an entry in your model.rb to create a method or a scope to get the data & allow you to link it to the current_user more easily & even drop some directed SQL query with the `.where` method to pull that information up if performance is an issue.

---

I spotted a second optimization in there ... if everything really is working - don't worry about this!

And don't forget about the strong_parameters nesting to do this fully ... [Strong Param white listing](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#strong-parameters-gotcha)

```
Basic format ... `.permit(:id, :something, slide_attributes: [:id, :name, :whatever, :_destroy])
```

Comment: I think there is a `user_id` in `Slide` because the creator of a post might not be the same as the creator of the slide. Also the code `current_user.Post.find ... ` that does not work. Should be sth like `current_user.posts.find_first(id:...).slides`. Also the `current_user.post.slides.build` is wrong: the two consecutive builds are needed (first you build a new post on the association --so the user-id is set correctly, then you build a slide, so the post-id will be set correctly, when saving it together)

Comment: Redacted second part - on the first part is that because find() method will return all entries found?

Comment: Also, would I leave the params[:id] or drop that too?

Comment: Stil wrong, you write `current_user.Post` <-- the class??? that does not make sense, that does not exist. But `current_user.posts` does, and then on that association you can search for a post with the given `id` (and the id we want to find is indeed `params[:id]`)

Comment: I need to hack around on this ... I've made the formula work before, but referencing the Model is something i try to do rarely & when stiff is dicey